# Complex If statement not triggering [PHP]

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make  redirect if the user is not signed in. 
so it should read like this:

If FName is unset and $page does not equal 'new host' or 'login'
then set header to login and set error message.

All the parts work on their own, but not when I try to assemble them.

**Edit, I have it working with a switch now but I'm still intrigued on why this *if* didn't work.**

The || means true if either condition is true.

The and checks to see if the leading and following conditions are true.

Should I be using && or does that make a difference?

Here is my code:

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['FName']) and 
( $page == '/e-Party/Login/Login.php' ||  $page == '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php')){

echo "not logged in";

$_SESSION['Error'] =
 "you must login to use our site,<br>. Or create a account if you don't have one"; 
  header( 'Location: /e-Party/Login/Login.php' );
  exit();
 }
```

Edit,  here is my working switch.

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['FName']))
switch ($page) {
   case '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php':    
   break;

   case '/e-Party/Login/Login.php':    
   break;  

   default:
   $_SESSION['Error'] =
   "you must login to use our site,<br>. Or creat a account if you dont   have one"; 
   header('Location: /e-Party/Login/Login.php');
   exit();
}
```

A comment helps much more than a down vote, thank you for reading.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? If so, and you think it's worth it, you can answer your own question (otherwise you can delete it).

Comment: @Joe I would like to know why the **if** it didn't work.
I want to learn what I was doing wrong.

Comment: @WhiteShadow see my answer for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `if` and `switch` are **not** equivalent: the `switch` version would be equivalent to

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['FName']) && $page != '/e-Party/Login/Login.php' &&  $page != '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php') {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Does php not allow using parentheses to do operations? Or was I just making things too complected?

Comment: You were just using the wrong logic, try writing a truth table for your `if` and mine, you'll see different results.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the if to a switch and it works perfectly as I intended.

```
if ( !isset($_SESSION['FName']))
switch ($page) {
  case '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php':    
  break;

  case '/e-Party/Login/Login.php':    
  break;  

  default:
  $_SESSION['Error'] =
  "you must login to use our site,<br>. Or creat a account if you dont   have one"; 
  header('Location: /e-Party/Login/Login.php');
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> If FName is unset and $page does not equal 'new host' or 'login' ...

But you wrote (in PHP)

```
if  !isset($_SESSION['FName']) and 
 ($page == '/e-Party/Login/Login.php' ||  $page == '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php')
```

That is, page equals A or page equals B.  To make PHP match English:

```
if  !isset($_SESSION['FName']) and 
 ($page != '/e-Party/Login/Login.php' ||  $page != '/e-Party/NewHost/NewHost.php')
```

which is flawed.  It is equivalent to

```
if  !isset($_SESSION['FName'])
```